# Not able to resolve the error in PL/SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm writing a stored function called MAKE_EMAIL that will accept input arguments for first name and lastname and will return a varchar2 value containing the email address in the form of first initial of the firstname followed by the full last name followed by @hpu.edu.

Ex: Calling:

```
select make_email('Edward','Souza')
from dual
```

... would return the single value:

```
'esouza@hpu.edu'
```

Please consider the following code for a function:

Code:

```
create or replace function MAKE_EMAIL(lastname varchar2(10),firstname varchar2(10))
 return VARCHAR 
IS

  email VARCHAR2;

 BEGIN

 email := substr(lastname ,1,1)|| firstname || '@hpu.edu';
RETURN email;

END;
  /
```

After running above function, I'm getting some errors. Please find the errors below. Please let me know how can I remove these errors or anything wrong with above code?

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION MAKE_EMAIL:

LINE/COL ERROR
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1/38     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
     following:
     := . ) , @ % default character
     The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

1/61     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
     following:
     := . ) , @ % default character
     The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

Here is the link for error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmjhbvie1c7dbcx/Error.png

Comment: @Mat I'm working on SQL Plus. Do you know how to copy and paste from there? Is there anything wrong with the dropbox link ?

Comment: Apart from what Mat points out, this question will be useless for everyone when you remove the picture from your Dropbox account.

Comment: @Mat: Updated the Question with text error message.

Comment: you'd probably want to apply a lower() function to the names, i think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot specify the size of a `varchar2` parameter to a stored procedure or function. Just remove the two size specifications in your function's declaration and it should compile (assuming no other syntax errors).

On the other hand, the `email` variable does need a size constraint. So specify one when you declare that.

The max. size for `varchar2` in PL/SQL is [32k](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10472/datatypes.htm), so should be more than enough for your use case. If you need to restrict that, do it in your function body.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but it didn't work. I'm getting the same error except the column number changed from 38 to 37 in first error and 61 to 59 in second.

Comment: You need to replace `varchar2(10)` with just `varchar2` for the two parameters, and add a size spec for the `email` variable. I don't know what you did, but doing these two things does make a compilable procedure.

Comment: Replacing varchar2(10) with varchar2 did remove the first two errors but I'm still getting the following error:

Warning: Function created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for FUNCTION MAKE_EMAIL:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/9      PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 ..
         32767)

Comment: What did you change the line `email varchar2` to?

Comment: Not really. I would like you to follow the answer I posted, and add a reasonable size constraint on the email variable. Something like `email varchar2(256);`.

Comment: It did work. Just now I changed email varchar2 to email varchar2(10).

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Aak, _reasonable_ size constraint. 10 is too short for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function MAKE_EMAIL(lastname varchar2,firstname varchar2)
return VARCHAR2 
IS email VARCHAR2(28);
BEGIN
 email := substr(lastname ,1,1)|| firstname || '@hpu.edu';
RETURN email;
END;​
/
```